# Orbit and stabilizer of the representation of multiplication decomposition of $U(3)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, fiber-bundles

We know that in SU(2), we have the multiplication of 2-dimensional representation (rep) decomposed as 
$$
2 \times 2= 1+3 \tag{a}
$$
where 1 is the singlet of SU(2). And 3 is the adjoint of SU(2) and vecto rep of SO(3). We can ask what is the orbit and stabilizer of each element.

1. For the 3 in the above eq. (a), we should have the base space $S^2$ as the orbit and the fiber $S^1$ as the stabilizer, with the following relations:
   $$
   S^1 \hookrightarrow S^3 \to S^2
   $$
   $$
   \text{stabilizer}\hookrightarrow \text{total space} \to \text{orbit}
   $$
   Naively, I write 
   $$U(1) \hookrightarrow SU(2) \to SO(3),$$
   as the SO(3) is the orbit that each object in $3$ can move around in the SO(3) space, while the stabilizer (a certain action of U(1)) makes the object invariant.
   The more proper way to write $SU(2)/U(1)=\mathbf{CP}^1$ as complex protective space.
   However, if we consider the total space as U(2), then the relations become:
   $$U(1) \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \hookrightarrow U(2) \to \frac{U(2)}{U(1) \times \mathbb{Z}_2},$$
2. For the 1 in the above eq. (a), which is a trivial representation of SU(2), thus we have the object invariant under the full SU(2), thus we have,
   $$SU(2) \hookrightarrow SU(2) \to pt,$$
   the orbit is a single point. If we consider the full U(2) as the total space that can act on the SU(2) fundamentals, we have
   $$SU(2) \hookrightarrow U(2) \to U(1)/\mathbb{Z}_2,$$

> What are the orbits and stabilizers of the right hand side objects in the multiplication of 3-dimensional representation of SU(3):
>   $$
> 3 \times 3= \bar{3}+6 \tag{b}
> $$
>   $$
> 3 \times \bar{3}= 1+8 \tag{c}
> $$
>
> question: What are the orbits and stabilizers of $\bar{3}$, $6$ and $1$, $8$ in the above decompositions, if we view the total space as SU(3) or U(3)?

Namely, what is
$$
\text{stabilizer}\hookrightarrow SU(3) \to \text{orbit},
$$
$$
\text{stabilizer}\hookrightarrow U(3) \to \text{orbit},
$$
for each of $\bar{3}$, $6$ and $1$, $8$ in the above decomposition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $$
   3 \times 3= \bar{3}+6 \tag{b}
   $$

(1). Given the $\bar{3}$ as the pair of U(3) or SU(3) fundamentals, we have the leftover invariant subgroup as $SU(2) \times U(1)$. For example, we can choose the $\bar{3}$ as the first 2-component out of 3-component of fundamentals, in order to form an anti-symmetric pair. In this case, we can write $SU(2) \times U(1) =SU(2)_{1,2} \times U(1)_{3}$ which indicates that the $SU(2)$ is rotating in the first 2-component subspace, and the $U(1)$ is acting on the 3rd component. We use a similar notations below. We then have
$$
SU(2)_{1,2} \hookrightarrow SU(3) \to \mathbf{CP}^2 \times (S^1)_{1,2,3},
$$
$$
SU(2)_{1,2} \times U(1)_{3} \hookrightarrow U(3) \to (\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes S^1) .
$$
The notation $\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes S^1$ is meant to say that the
$\mathbf{CP}^2$ has a nontrivial fibration by the $S^1$.

(2). Given the $6$ as the pair of U(3) or SU(3) fundamentals, we have the left over invariant subgroup as $U(1) \times U(1)$. For example, we can choose the $6$ as the first 2-component out of 3-component of fundamentals, in order to form an anti-symmetric pair. In this case, we can write $U(1) \times U(1) =U(1)_{1,2} \times U(1)_{3}$ which indicates that the $U(1)_{1,2}$ is rotating in the first 2-component subspace, and the $U(1)_3$ is acting on the 3rd component.
We then have
$$
U(1)_{1,2} \hookrightarrow SU(3) \to (\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes \mathbf{CP}^1) \times (S^1)_{1,2,3},
$$
$$
U(1)_{1,2} \times U(1)_{3} \hookrightarrow U(3) \to ((\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes \mathbf{CP}^1)\rtimes S^1) .
$$

2.
$$
3 \times \bar{3}= 1+8 \tag{c}
$$
(1) Given the $1$ as the pair of U(3) or SU(3) fundamental and anti-fundamental, we have
$$
SU(3) \hookrightarrow SU(3) \to 1,
$$
$$
SU(3) \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \hookrightarrow U(3) \to  S^1/\mathbb{Z}_6.
$$

(2) Given the $8$ as the pair of U(3) or SU(3) fundamental and anti-fundamental, we have
$$
U(1)_{1,2} \hookrightarrow SU(3) \to  (\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes \mathbf{CP}^1) \times (S^1)_{1,2,3},
$$
$$
U(1)_{1,2} \times U(1)_{3} \hookrightarrow U(3) \to   ((\mathbf{CP}^2 \rtimes \mathbf{CP}^1)\rtimes S^1).
$$

p.s. The above is the tentative answer (so far), if I understand your question correctly.