# Non-Abelian subgroups and invariants in a unitary group 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Related to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733426/), let us redefine their $\{P_1, P_2,  P_3, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3 \}$ to something somehow different.

Let $$G=U(3),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of U(3). Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-3 (3 by 3) matrices.

1. Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(3) $$  such that

   > $$ 
   > k^T \{P_1, P_2,  P_3, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3 \} k =\{P_1, P_2,  P_3, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3\}.
   > $$
   >   This means that set $\{P_1, P_2,  P_3, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. 
   >   Here $k^T$ is the transpose of $k$.
   >   What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K$?

Here we define: 
$$
P_1 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_3 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $k^T P_a k= \pm P_b$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{1,2,3 \}$. But overall the full set $ \{P_1, P_2,  P_3, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

There must be a trivial element $k=$ the rank-3 identity matrix. But what else can it allow?

> How could we determine the complete $K$?

Comment: and also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (and the method) is the same as the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733426/discrete-non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group).

> **Answer.** The subgroup $K$ of $U(3)$ containing invariant matrices are isomorphic to the finite group
>   $$
> \mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4 \cong\langle i\rangle\times D(2,3,4)
> $$
>   where $\langle i\rangle=\{\pm I,\pm iI\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $D(2,3,4)$ is the [von Dyck group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Von_Dyck_group) which is [isomorphic to $S_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4).
>
> More specifically, $D(2,3,4)=\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^3=c^4=abc=I\rangle$ is represented in $U(3)$ as follows:
>   $$
> a = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> c = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Here is more detailed calculation:

> **Claim 1.** The matrices in $U(3)$ satisfying $k^TP_1k=\pm P_1$ are
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \quad\text{or}\quad
> \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   where $|\alpha|=|\beta|=|\gamma|=1$ and $\alpha\beta=\pm1$.

*Proof.* Let us find $k=(k_{ij})$ such that $k^TP_1k=\pm P_1$. It implies the following equations
$$
\begin{gather*}
k_{11}k_{21} = k_{12}k_{22} = k_{13}k_{23} = 0, \\
k_{11}k_{22} + k_{12}k_{21} = \pm1, \tag{*} \\
k_{11}k_{23} + k_{13}k_{21} = k_{12}k_{23} + k_{13}k_{22} = 0. 
\end{gather*}
$$
Note that $k_{13}=0$. Otherwise $k_{21}=k_{22}=k_{23}=0$, and it contradicts to $k\in U(3)$. Similarly, $k_{23}=0$. Moreover, $k_{31}=k_{32}=0$ since $k\in U(3)$. Now the remaining equations in (*)
$$
k_{11}k_{21} = k_{12}k_{22} = 0, \quad
k_{11}k_{22} + k_{12}k_{21} = \pm1
$$
give the matrices in the claim depending on $k_{11}\neq0$ or $0$.

Fix a permutation matrix $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then we have
$$
QP_1Q^T=P_2 \quad\text{and}\quad Q^2P_1(Q^2)^T=Q^TP_1Q=P_3
$$

In a similar way as the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733426/discrete-non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group), we have
$$
\begin{align*}
K_{00} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_1 k=\pm P_1\} &= K_{00} \\
K_{02} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_1 k=\pm P_2\} &= K_{00}Q^T \\
K_{01} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_1 k=\pm P_3\} &= K_{00}Q \\
K_{10} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_2 k=\pm P_1\} &= QK_{00} \\
K_{12} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_2 k=\pm P_2\} &= QK_{00}Q^T \\
K_{11} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_2 k=\pm P_3\} &= QK_{00}Q \\
K_{20} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_3 k=\pm P_1\} &= Q^TK_{00} \\
K_{22} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_3 k=\pm P_2\} &= Q^TK_{00}Q^T \\
K_{21} \equiv \{k\in U(3) \mid k^TP_3 k=\pm P_3\} &= Q^TK_{00}Q
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, we have the following 16×6 invariant matrices:

> **Claim 2.** For $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\alpha\beta=\pm1$, $\alpha\gamma=\pm1$, and $\beta\gamma=\pm1$,
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> K_{00}\cap K_{12}\cap K_{21} &\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \quad
> K_{00}\cap K_{11}\cap K_{22} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \\
> K_{02}\cap K_{10}\cap K_{21} &\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 0 & \gamma & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad
> K_{02}\cap K_{11}\cap K_{20} \Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha \\ \beta & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \gamma & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
> K_{01}\cap K_{10}\cap K_{22} &\Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \beta \\ \gamma & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad
> K_{01}\cap K_{12}\cap K_{20} \Rightarrow\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & \beta & 0 \\ \gamma & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}
> $$

Comment: @ ChoF, you are correct. Sorry I am partially paralyzed and handicapped so I may make mistake. However, I can type. I saw there was a S$_4$, but I am not sure that it is the full answer. I was worried that maybe there is additional new sectors that can be hidden somewhere. Thanks! +1

Comment: How do you know that there is no more than ℤ4×S4? If you are certain, then I can accept it as an answer very soon. What I meant is that there could be more.

Comment: @ ChoF, what I am even more puzzled is this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932/. I checked this one also contains the Z4 $\times$ S4, but I doubt it is the complete answer -- there must be more... The structure is related to [this another deeper question I think](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745276/)

Comment: In this one, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932, we can find a U(3) transforming between $P_1$ and $P_4$, between $P_2$ and $P_5$ and so on, many more choices. So I suppose it is more than Z4 × S4.

Comment: @ ChoF, I would accept your answer, but just in case, I think by me checking this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932, I find possible new subgroups not included in your case (...)

Comment: @annieheart I don't agree with you. Just show me one matrix that is not generated by $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\langle i\rangle$ above. If so, my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @annieheart Moreover, the three matrices $a$, $b$, and $c$ preserve $\{P_4,P_5,P_6\}$ in [your new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932/subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-u3).

Comment: For this question, that I agreed. (I guessed you said "my answer is correct") I am saying that for the other question linked has a larger group other than Z4 × S4.

Comment: The group we discussed should be contained as the orbit (base manifold) in my other bounty post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745276. Here we talked about the discrete cases, there are continuous.