# Subgroups and invariants in a unitary group $U(3)$ mixing multiplets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is related to [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746932/), but an enriched version of the problem. Now we require the richer form of $P_{x1},P_{x2},P_{x3},P_{y1},P_{y2},P_{y3},P_{z1},P_{z2},P_{z3}$.

Let $$G=U(3),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of $U(3)$. Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-3 (3 by 3) matrix.

Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(3) $$  such that

> $$ 
> k^T \{ \pm P_{x1},\pm P_{x2},\pm P_{x3},\pm P_{y1},\pm P_{y2},\pm P_{y3},\pm P_{z1},\pm P_{z2},\pm P_{z3} \} k =\{ \pm P_{x1},\pm P_{x2},\pm P_{x3},\pm P_{y1},\pm P_{y2},\pm P_{y3},\pm P_{z1},\pm P_{z2},\pm P_{z3}\}.
> $$
>   This means that set $\{ \pm P_{x1},\pm P_{x2},\pm P_{x3},\pm P_{y1},\pm P_{y2},\pm P_{y3},\pm P_{z1},\pm P_{z2},\pm P_{z3}\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. 
>   Here $k^T$ is the transpose of $k$.
>   What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K$?

Here we define:

$$ 
P_{x1} = 
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) ,\;\;\;\; P_{y1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_{z1} =
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
$$
P_{x2} = 
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) ,\;\;\;\; P_{y2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_{z2} =
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
$$
  P_{x3} =  \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_{y3} =
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_{z2} =
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $k^T P_a k= \pm P_b$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3 \}$. But overall the full set $ \{ \pm P_{x1},\pm P_{x2},\pm P_{x3},\pm P_{y1},\pm P_{y2},\pm P_{y3},\pm P_{z1},\pm P_{z2},\pm P_{z3}\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

There must be a trivial element $k=$ the rank-3 identity matrix. But what else can it allow?

> How could we determine the complete $K$? What is the order of $K$? What is $K$ isomorphic to? [A more familiar group like dihedral, symmetry groups, cyclic, etc?]

Comment: Maybe useful info: One should take into account for example, $$(e^{i {\theta} \hat{n} \cdot \hat{\sigma}/2})^T
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
- 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)e^{i {\theta} \hat{n} \cdot \hat{\sigma}/2} =
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sqrt{i} & 0  \\
 0 & -\sqrt{i}   \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
- 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sqrt{i} & 0  \\
 0 & -\sqrt{i}   \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=
-{i}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: when $\theta=\pi/2$ and when $\hat n=n_x=1$ or $\hat n=n_y=1$ or $\hat n=n_z=1$ with $|\hat n|=1$, you should be able to rotate between the $P_x,P_y,P_z$ within an SO(3) out of the SU(2) inside the U(3).

Comment: $\hat \sigma$ is the three Pauli matrices as a set of 3.

Comment: Note $\theta=\pm \pi/2$, etc.

Comment: Note also $$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & i  \\
 i & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\frac{1}{ i}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & i  \\
 i & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
 1 & 0  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: @wonderich I agree in the case of $U(2)$ or when we find $K$ preserving $\{P_{x1},P_{y1},P_{z1}\}$. But the situation becomes quite different if $P_{x2}$ and $P_{x3}$ are included. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the set of the matrices by $\mathcal{P}=\{\pm P_{xi},\pm P_{yi},\pm P_{zi} \mid 1\leq i\leq 3\}$.

Let $K=\{k \in U(3) \mid k^TPk\in\mathcal{P}\text{ for all $P\in\mathcal{P}$}\}$, the set of matrices under which $\mathcal{P}$ is invariant.

> **Claim 1.** There is no $k\in K$ such that $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{z1}$.

*Proof.* Denote by $k=(k_{ij})$. Since $k$ is unitary, $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{z1}$ implies
$$
P_{x1}k = \begin{pmatrix} k_{21} & k_{22} & k_{23} \\ k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \pm \begin{pmatrix} -i\bar k_{11} & -i\bar k_{12} & 0 \\ -i\bar k_{21} & -i\bar k_{22} & 0 \\ -i\bar k_{31} & -i\bar k_{32} & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \pm \bar kP_{z1}
$$
and thus $k_{13}=k_{23}=k_{31}=k_{32}=0$.

We now have $k=\begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & 0 \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k_{33} \end{pmatrix}\in U(2)\times U(1)$. Notice that $k_{33}\neq 0$.

Then $k^TP_{xi}k$ have the matrix form as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
k^TP_{x1}k &= \begin{pmatrix} 2k_{11}k_{21} & k_{11}k_{22}+k_{12}k_{21} & 0 \\ k_{11}k_{22}+k_{12}k_{21} & 2k_{12}k_{22} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \pm \begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \pm P_{z1} \\
k^TP_{x2}k &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & k_{11}k_{33} \\ 0 & 0 & k_{12}k_{33} \\ k_{11}k_{33} & k_{12}k_{33} & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \pm P_{x2} \text{ or } \pm P_{x3}
\end{align*}
$$

From the first equation that is our assumption, we know that all $k_{11}$, $k_{12}$, $k_{21}$, $k_{22}$ are not zero.

Remember that $k_{33}\neq0$. If $k^TP_{x2}k=\pm P_{x2}$, then $k_{12}=0$, which contradicts to $k_{12}\neq0$. Similarly, if $k^TP_{x2}k=\pm P_{x3}$, then $k_{11}=0$, which contradicts to $k_{11}\neq0$.

> **Claim 2.** There is no $k\in K$ such that $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{y1}$.

*Proof.* Completely the same as **Claim 1**.

Set $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in U(3)$.
Then $Q^T=Q^{-1}=Q^2$ and
$$
\begin{gather*}
QP_{x1}Q^T=P_{x2}, \quad QP_{x2}Q^T=P_{x3}, \quad QP_{x3}Q^T=P_{x1} \\
QP_{y1}Q^T=-P_{y2}, \quad QP_{y2}Q^T=-P_{y3}, \quad QP_{y3}Q^T=P_{y1} \\
QP_{z1}Q^T=P_{z2}, \quad QP_{z2}Q^T=P_{z3}, \quad QP_{z3}Q^T=P_{z1} \\
\end{gather*}
$$
It implies that if $k\in K$ then $kQ\in K$ and $kQ^T\in K$.

> **Claim 3.** There is no $k\in K$ such that $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{z2}$ or $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{z3}$.

*Proof.* If $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{z2}$, then $(kQ)^TP_{x1}(kQ)=Q^T(k^TP_{x1}k)Q=\pm Q^TP_{z2}Q=\pm P_{z1}$, which contradicts to **Claim 1**.

> **Claim 4.** There is no $k\in K$ such that $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{y2}$ or $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{y3}$.

*Proof.* Completely the same as **Claim 3**.

Now we have a conclusion that if $k\in K$, then $k^TP_{x1}k=\pm P_{xi}$ for some $1\leq i\leq 3$. Moreover, we already know [the solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746578/non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-2/2748056) in this case, that is,

> The subgroup $K$ of $U(3)$ containing invariant matrices are isomorphic to the finite group
>   $$
> \mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4 \simeq\langle i\rangle\times D(2,3,4)
> $$
>   where $\langle i\rangle=\{\pm I,\pm iI\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $D(2,3,4)$ is the [von Dyck group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Von_Dyck_group) which is [isomorphic to $S_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4).
>
> More specifically, $D(2,3,4)=\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^3=c^4=abc=I\rangle$ is represented in $U(3)$ as follows:
>   $$
> a = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> c = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

It is routine to check that $\langle i\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}_4$ and the three generators $a,b,c$ of $D(2,3,4)\simeq S_4$ preserve the matrices $\mathcal{P}$.

**Therefore, the answer of this question is the same $K$ as above.**

Comment: I saw your message, this is to my surprise!!!

Comment: +1, @ ChoF, @ wonderich but I believe that some richer structure will show up, based on the comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752655/ -- this is related to the new bounty question I pose [still unsolved].

Comment: The new one: I am guessing the answer is an order 8 quaternion then in U(2)?