# Subgroups and invariants in a unitary group U(3)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is related to [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746578), but an enriched version of the problem. Now we require the richer form of $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6$.

Let $$G=U(3),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of U(3). Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-3 (3 by 3) matrices.

Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(3) $$  such that

> $$ 
> k^T \{P_1, P_2,  P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3,-P_4,-P_5,-P_6 \} k =\{P_1, P_2,  P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3,-P_4,-P_5,-P_6\}.
> $$
>   This means that set $\{P_1, P_2,  P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3,-P_4,-P_5,-P_6\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. 
>   Here $k^T$ is the transpose of $k$.
>   What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K$?

Here we define: 
$$
P_1 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_3 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
$$
P_4 =\sqrt{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_5 =
\sqrt{2}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_6 =
\sqrt{2}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $k^T P_a k= \pm P_b$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$. But overall the full set $ \{P_1, P_2,  P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6, -P_1, - P_2, - P_3,-P_4,-P_5,-P_6\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

There must be a trivial element $k=$ the rank-3 identity matrix. But what else can it allow?

> How could we determine the complete $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (and the method) is the same as the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746578/non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-2/2748056).

> The subgroup $K$ of $U(3)$ containing invariant matrices are isomorphic to the finite group
>   $$
> \mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4 \cong\langle i\rangle\times D(2,3,4)
> $$
>   where $\langle i\rangle=\{\pm I,\pm iI\}\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $D(2,3,4)$ is the [von Dyck group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Von_Dyck_group) which is [isomorphic to $S_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4).
>
> More specifically, $D(2,3,4)=\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^3=c^4=abc=I\rangle$ is represented in $U(3)$ as follows:
>   $$
> a = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
> c = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

1. It is a fact from elementary linear algebra that $P_a$ and $k^TP_ak$ have the same rank because $k\in U(3)$ is non-singular. Notice that $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are of rank $2$, but $P_4,P_5,P_6$ are of rank $1$. Thus, if $k^TP_ak=\pm P_b$, then either $a,b\in\{1,2,3\}$ or $a,b\in\{4,5,6\}$.
2. All the matrices preserving $\{P_i\mid 1\leq i\leq 6\}$ also preserve $\{P_i\mid 1\leq i\leq 3\}$.
3. Because we already know all the matrices preserving $\{P_i\mid 1\leq i\leq 3\}$ in the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746578/non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-2/2748056), it suffices to check whether those matrices preserve $\{P_i\mid 4\leq i\leq 6\}$ or not.
4. Note that the three generators $a,b,c$ preserve $\{P_i\mid 4\leq i\leq 6\}$ as follows
   $$
   \begin{gather*}
   a^TP_4a=P_4, \quad b^TP_4b=P_5, \quad c^TP_4c=P_5 \\
   a^TP_5a=P_6, \quad b^TP_5b=P_6, \quad c^TP_5c=P_4 \\
   a^TP_6a=P_5, \quad b^TP_6b=P_4, \quad c^TP_6c=P_6
   \end{gather*}
   $$
5. It is trivial that $\langle i\rangle=\{\pm I,\pm iI\}$ preserve $\{P_i\mid 4\leq i\leq 6\}$.
6. Therefore we have the same solution as the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746578/non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-2/2748056).

Comment: @ ChoF +1, thanks -- I agree that S4 and Z4 are part of answers. How do we know that the $P_1,P_4,P_5$ *cannot* transform to each other?

Comment: The  S4 and Z4 cannot transform P1,P4,P5 to each other. But P1,P4,P5 are part of triplet $3$ under the SU(2) bifundamentals, $2 \otimes 2 =1 \oplus 3$, where 3 is the triplet under adjoint representation of SU(2), thus vector representation of SO(3).

Comment: Similarly, I am conjecturing that P3, P5, P6 can transform to each other under a U(3) subgroup, and P2, P4, P6 can transform to each other under a U(3) subgroup. Or it could be that there is a subtle way to define the SU(2)'s quotient group SO(3) and its finite subgroup within the U(3). See also /math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746912/

Comment: @annieheart $P_1,P_2,P_3$ have rank $2$ and $P_4,P_5,P_6$ have rank $1$. Notice that $k^TP_ak$ preserves the rank information. So $P_1,P_2,P_3$ cannot transform to $P_4,P_5,P_6$.

Comment: @annieheart This question is finding the group of invariant matrices which preserve the set $\{\pm P_i\mid 1\leq i\leq 6\}$. I don't know why you say "The S4 and Z4 cannot transform P1,P4,P5 to each other." Actually $Z_4$ which is generated by the diagonal matrix $i\times I$ transforms $\{\pm P_1,\pm P_4,\pm P_5\}$ to itself. Moreover, the generators $a,b,c$ of $D(2,3,4)\simeq S^4$ transform the set $\{\pm P_1,\pm P_2,\pm P_3\}$ to itself and $\{\pm P_4,\pm P_5,\pm P_6\}$ to itself.

Comment: Can you illuminate the statements about "P1,P2,P3 have rank 2 and P4,P5,P6 have rank 1" I know that P1,P2,P3 have a 2 by 2 matrix and P4,P5,P6 have only a single 1 component. But what is the problem to transform between them? [I was worrying about the additional subgroups not found, but thanks in case, we need to be careful.]

Comment: @ ChoF, the correct version of the story should be instead this form. What you said is correct. And I what I meant to relating the different "triplet" story should be more correctly addressed by this new modified question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746912/subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-u3-mixing-multiplets.

Comment: I am expecting a dihedral group there that is a subgroup of SO(3) that is not included in your S4 x Z4 case.

Comment: In the new linked question (which was what I should ask originally), I am taking the triplet 3 out of $2 \otimes 2 =1 \oplus 3$ in SU(2), where the 3 is the $x,y,z$ directions, so I should get a SO(3) rotational subgroup rotating between them -- that is why I am guessing a dihedral group  -- but I cannot prove it

Comment: @annieheart Updated the answer with the statement about preserving rank. The fact comes from elementary linear algebra.

Comment: @annieheart Even the case of [Subgroups and invariants in a unitary group $U(3)$ mixing multiplets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746912/subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group-u3-mixing-multiplets), the subgroup $K$ of invariant matrices may be the same. In my opinion, $P_x$'s transform into $P_x$'s, and $P_y$'s into $P_y$'s, and $P_z$'s into $P_z$'s.

Comment: You can rotate $P_x,P_y,P_z$ through $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sqrt{i} & 0  \\
 0 & -\sqrt{i}   \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & i  \\
 i & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, etc, and so on.

Comment: p.s. Note someone posted helpful comments in the link question.

Comment: I adjust the order of matrices - to match the earlier questions so it may be easier to implement your previous result

Comment: @ChoF and @ annie heart, I ask this new one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754163/invariant-subgroup-in-a-self-conjugate-pair-multiplication-in-unitary-group-u3 -- maybe this is the better version of question that annie should ask. Please feel free to leave comments