# Invariant subgroup in a Hermitian self-conjugate pair multiplication in Unitary Group $U(3)$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Inspired by @ChoF's [exploration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754163/invariant-subgroup-in-a-self-conjugate-pair-multiplication-in-unitary-group-u3), I like to post a similar but possibly richer structure related to the decompositions of $U(3)$ or $SU(3)$ representation multiplications $3 \otimes \bar 3 = 1 \oplus  8.$

3 is in the fundamental and 8 is in the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$. Below I modify and preserve the structure of questions from ([Invariant subgroup in a self-conjugate pair multiplication in Unitary Group $U(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754163/invariant-subgroup-in-a-self-conjugate-pair-multiplication-in-unitary-group-u3))

Let $$G=U(3),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of U(3). Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-3 (3 by 3) matrices. Now we take a set of $P$ matrices from [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices#Matrices) and generalized [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). And all  $P$ matrices are [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).

Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(3) $$  such that

> $$ 
> k^\dagger \{\pm P_1, \pm  P_2,\pm   P_3,\pm  P_4,\pm  P_5, \pm  P_6, \pm  P_7, \pm  P_8, \pm  P_9 \} k$$ 
>   $$=\{\pm P_1, \pm  P_2,\pm   P_3,\pm  P_4,\pm  P_5, \pm  P_6, \pm  P_7, \pm  P_8, \pm  P_9\}.
> $$
>   This means that the full set $\{\pm P_1, \pm  P_2,\pm   P_3,\pm  P_4,\pm  P_5, \pm  P_6, \pm  P_7, \pm  P_8, \pm  P_9\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. 
>   Here $$k^\dagger \equiv (k^*)^T$$ is the complex conjugate ($*$) transpose ($T$) of $k$.
>   What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K \subset G$?

Here we define: 
$$
P_1 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -i & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_3 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
P_4 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_5 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & -i \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\;
P_6 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ 
$$P_7 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_8 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i \\
 0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\;
P_9 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $$k^\dagger P_a k= \pm P_b$$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$. But overall the full set $ \{\pm P_1, \pm  P_2,\pm   P_3,\pm  P_4,\pm  P_5, \pm  P_6, \pm  P_7, \pm  P_8, \pm  P_9 \}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

> Please determine the complete $K$.

p.s. I modify the Gell-Mann matrices to a most symmetric form in accordance.

Answer (score 2):

The nine matrices $P_i$ can be divided into three sets:
$$
\mathcal P_1=\{\pm P_1,\pm P_2,\pm P_3\}, \quad
\mathcal P_2=\{\pm P_4,\pm P_5,\pm P_6\}, \quad
\mathcal P_3=\{\pm P_7,\pm P_8,\pm P_9\}.
$$

According to the transformation $k^\dagger\mathcal P_i k$, we have 6 cases as follows:

1. **(All fixed)** If $\mathcal P_1\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_1$, $\mathcal P_2\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_2$, $\mathcal P_3\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_3$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$
2. **($\mathcal P_1$ fixed)** If $\mathcal P_1\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_1$, $\mathcal P_2\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_3$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$
3. **($\mathcal P_2$ fixed)** If $\mathcal P_2\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_2$, $\mathcal P_1\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_3$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & \beta & 0 \\ \gamma & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$
4. **($\mathcal P_3$ fixed)** If $\mathcal P_3\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_3$, $\mathcal P_1\leftrightarrow\mathcal P_2$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 0 & \gamma & 0  \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$
5. **(No fixed)** If $\mathcal P_1\rightarrow\mathcal P_2\rightarrow\mathcal P_3\rightarrow\mathcal P_1$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha \\ \beta & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \gamma & 0  \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$
6. **(No fixed)** If $\mathcal P_1\rightarrow\mathcal P_3\rightarrow\mathcal P_2\rightarrow\mathcal P_1$, then we have
   $$
   k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \beta \\ \gamma & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)
   $$

For all six cases, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in U(1)$ must satisfy
$$
(\alpha=\pm\gamma \text{ or} \pm i\gamma) \quad\text{and}\quad
(\beta=\pm\gamma \text{ or} \pm i\gamma)
$$

> **Answer.** The invariant subgroup $K$ of $U(3)$ is isomorphic to the infinite group
>   $$
> (U(1) \times \mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4) \rtimes_\varphi S_3
> $$

*Note. The answer is quite related to the [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754163/invariant-subgroup-in-a-self-conjugate-pair-multiplication-in-unitary-group-u3).*