# Subgroups and invariants in a unitary group $U(2)$ mixing multiplets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups

This is related to [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746912/), but a simplified version of the problem. However, the form of $P_x,P_y,P_z$ are different and richer.

Let $$G=U(2),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of U(2). Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-2 (2 by 2) matrices.

Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(2) $$  such that

> $$ 
> k^T \{P_x, P_y,  P_z, -P_x, - P_y, - P_z\} k =\{P_x, P_y,  P_z, -P_x, - P_y, - P_z\}.
> $$
>   This means that set $\{P_x, P_y,  P_z, -P_x, - P_y, - P_z\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. 
>   Here $k^T$ is the transpose of $k$.
>   What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K$?

Here we define: 
$$
P_x =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0  \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_y =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 0  \\
 0 & 1  \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; P_z =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -i & 0  \\
 0 & -i  \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $k^T P_a k= \pm P_b$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{x,y,z \}$. But overall the full set $ \{P_x, P_y,  P_z, -P_x, - P_y, - P_z\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

There must be a trivial element $k=$ the rank-2 identity matrix. But what else can it allow?

> How could we determine the complete $K$?

Comment: I am guessing the answer is an order 8 quaternion then?

Comment: see also https://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/su2-and-the-quaternions/

Comment: Sorry I mean the answer contain an order 8 quaternion (in a larger non-Abelian group), but then there is some additional cyclic group.

Comment: $P_z$ is a scalar matrix, fixed by any conjugation. You probably have a typo.

Comment: This is correct -- I wrote what I mean, see also the previous question. The similar forms. $P_z$ is $-i$ times an identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Answer.** The subgroup $K$ of invariant matrices in $U(2)$ is isomorphic to the finite group
>   $$
> \operatorname{SL}(2,3)\to G\to\mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}_2
> \quad\simeq\quad
> \mathbb{Z}_2\to G\to S_4) \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}_2
> $$
>   where $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$ is the special linear group of degree 2 over a field of 3 elements (order 24), which is isomorphic to the [binary von Dyck group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Binary_von_Dyck_group) with the parameters (2,3,3); it has the presentation: $\langle a,b,c \mid a^3=b^3=c^2=abc\rangle$.
>
> In other words, $K\cong G\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb{Z}_2$ for some subgroup $G\subset K$ and $G/\operatorname{SL}(2,3)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $G/\mathbb{Z}_2\simeq S_4$.

For whom is interested, I list the all $96=24\times 4$ invariant matricies of $K$:
$$
\begin{gather*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix}, \\
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ i & -i \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -i & i \end{pmatrix}, \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ i & i \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -i & -i \end{pmatrix}, \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ -i & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ -1 & -i \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ 1 & i \end{pmatrix}, \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1+i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ -1 & i \end{pmatrix},
\frac{(1-i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ 1 & -i \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
$$
product with $\langle i\rangle=\{\pm I,\pm iI\}$.

For given orders, the numbers of elements in $K$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4$ are as follows:

```
order | K        | Z4 x S4
--------------------------
1     | 1        | 1
2     | 19       | 19
3     | 8        | 8
4     | 20       | 44
6     | 8        | 8
8     | 24       | 0
12    | 16       | 16
--------------------------
total | 96       | 96
```

> This information shows that $K$ (GAP ID [96, 192]) in $U(2)$ is **not isomorphic** to the [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733426/discrete-non-abelian-subgroups-and-invariants-in-a-unitary-group) $\mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4$ (GAP ID [96,186]) in $U(3)$.

Comment: This is a surprising result to me again.

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is just a cyclic group generated by $i$ times an identity matrix, why do you need a semi direct product? Why not just a direct product?

Comment: @wonderich The difference between two groups $\mathbb{Z}_4\rtimes S_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4\times S_4$ were appended. Do you have any idea what this group is?

Comment: I understand that one can generate some of your group elements by an subgroup of SU(2) rotations $$e^{i {\theta} \hat{n} \cdot \hat{\sigma}/2}=\cos( \frac{\theta}{2})+ i \hat{n} \cdot \hat{\sigma} \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$ with $ \hat{\sigma}$-Pauli matrices and $\hat{n}=(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ with $|\hat{n}|=1$ and choose $n_x=1$ or $n_y=1$ or $n_z=1$ at $\theta=\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2, 2\pi,..$ or $\theta=m \pi/2$ with $m=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ where  $\theta$ is 4$\pi$ periodic.

Comment: This contains, e.g. $$n_z=1,\theta=\pi/2,\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sqrt{i} & 0  \\
 0 & -\sqrt{i}   \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right), $$, $$n_x=1,\theta=\pi/2,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & i  \\
 i & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right),$$
$$n_y=1,\theta=\pi/2,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 1 & 1  \\
 -1 & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: @wonderich $n_x$ and $n_y$ preserve $P_x,P_y,P_z$. But $n_z$ does not preserve $P_y$ and $P_z$. Note that $n_z^TP_yn_z=\begin{pmatrix} -i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix}$ and $n_z^TP_zn_z=I$.

Comment: +1, I wonder how do you know this group is complete? [another related motivation is based on this physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401307/construct-an-so3-rotation-inside-the-two-su2-fundamental-rotations, you guys may have interests too]

Comment: Sorry, I meant, a typo, what I said should hold as follows $$n_z=1, \theta=\pi/2, \quad\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sqrt{i} & 0  \\
 0 & \sqrt{-i}   \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right),$$

Comment: I use the same notations for Pauli matrices as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Comment: I think what I wrote is related to yours by:
$$\sqrt{i}=(1 + I)/\sqrt{2},\quad \sqrt{-i}=(1 - I)/\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: for example, in that notation, I find:
$$n_z^T P_x n_z = P_y$$
$$n_z^T P_y n_z = -P_x$$
$$n_z^T P_z n_z = P_z$$
and so on, which is like a subgroup of SO(3) rotation.

Comment: $\pm P_x, \pm P_y,\pm P_z$ are like three axes vectors along the $\pm x, \pm y, \pm z$. The $n_x,n_y,n_z$ are like the $\pi/2$ (90 degrees) rotations along the $x,y,z$ axes.

Comment: Because of the possible SO(3) subgroup structure, I think there may be some a dihedral group like finite group structure.

Comment: sorry my $x,y,z$ notations are the permutation relabeling of OP's $y,z,x$ by @ annie heart.

Comment: @annieheart Just calculate the matrices. 2 by 2 matrices are not hard to compute. I could get the 96 matrices with ease compared to the previous $U(3)$ case.

Comment: @wonderich I found $K$ from the [list of GAP small groups](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbimar/small_groups.pdf), and there was only one group of order 96 having the element order list given above.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I wonder is this earlier statement you said still true:

> More specifically, the cosets of $K/\langle i\rangle\simeq D(2,3,4)=\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^3=c^4=abc=I\rangle$ are
$$
a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
b = \frac{(1+i)}{2} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & i \\ 1 & i \end{pmatrix}, \quad
c = \frac{(1-i)}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that $a^2=b^3=abc=I$ and $c^4=-I$.

Comment: True of False. Yes or no?

Comment: @annieheart It's true. But $K/\langle i\rangle\simeq D(2,3,4)$ does not say that $K\simeq \langle i\rangle\rtimes D(2,3,4)$.

Comment: I am not sure your notations here above
$$\operatorname{SL}(2,3)\to K\to\mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}_2 ?$$

Comment: I know the group extensions, $K/N=Q$ means $N \to K \to Q$

Comment: Do you mean that
$1 \to \operatorname{SL}(2,3)\to K\to\mathbb{Z}_2  \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$
and it is also true that
$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_4=<i> \to K \to S_4 \to 1,$$
yes or no?

Comment: @annieheart There may be some confusion. I will fix the answer. The notation $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)\to G\to\mathbb{Z}_2)\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb{Z}_2$ is from [GAP information](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbimar/small_groups.pdf). It means that $K\simeq G\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb{Z}_2$ for some subgroup $G\subset K$ and $G/\operatorname{SL}(2,3)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I see -- thanks!

Comment: @ChoF, this may be also a problem that you can shed lights on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809107/the-orbitfold-space-of-symmetric-complex-matrix

Comment: p.s. 
now also with a bounty/