# The (orbifold) space of symmetric complex matrix 3 - simplified

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Let $K$ be a rank-2 symmetric complex matrix, such that the transpose
$K^T=K$ is itself.

Modifying [the previous attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809107/141334), let $V$ be a rank-2 matrix in the special unitary matrix, 
$$V \in  SU(2) .$$  (There is a Autonne-Takagi theorem helping for the case however only for $V \in   U(2)$, see the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809107/141334).)

Consider the identification between any K and K' of any rank-2
symmetric complex matrix,
$$
K\sim K',
$$
if it satisfies
$$
V^T K V =K',
$$
for any $V \in  SU(2) .$

question:

> 1. What is the real dimension of the new space of $K$ (under the
>      $K\sim K'$ and $V^T K V =K'$, for any $V \in SU(2) $ condition)?
> 2. How do we parametrize this new space of $K$ in terms of a rank-2
>      matrix (mod out the redundancy under the $K\sim K'$ and $V^T K V =K'$,
>      for any $V \in  SU(2) $ condition)?

(p.s. This space may be a called an orbifold space(?). i.e. The (orbifold) space of symmetric complex matrix after mod out a relation identifying a unitary matrix.)